# Ubuntu works slowly. Nothing loads and reboot takes 10 minutes

Tags: system

I started using Ubuntu 20.04 about 3 months ago. I installed it and it worked fine. Till today. None of applications starts. When I go to the settings (after 6 minutes) I see an information „NetworkManager needs to be running”. I tried updating the software but I cannot even summon a command sudo because it freezes whole terminal. Even reboot takes me 10 minutes now („a stop job is running for WPA/Network Manager etc.”. I’m a newbie with Ubuntu and I tried to look for an answer everywhere but cannot find anything.
[systemd-analyze blame output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG9N2.jpg)

[image: This is what I see after I try to shut down the system.]

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1297296/edit) your post with the output of `systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: You seem to have problems with NetworkManager starting and stopping.  Do you have any other network-related issues today?

Comment: @user535733 Not at all. To be honest I was using the internet earlier with no issues.

Comment: @KGIII All of it? Or just the top of it?

Comment: The top dozen or so should be fine. Be sure to use the code format so that it's readable, thanks.

Comment: @KGIII I uploaded a photo of the output of systemd-analyze blame (it was way easier) :)

Comment: Did you make any changes trying to prevent the system from suspending/sleeping? You can get rid of the network wait stuff, but that's not the main time consuming process.

Comment: @KGIII not really. As I said, I’m a newbie when it comes to ubuntu. Of course I work time to time with terminal but its mostly git. The Network process disturbs me the most. I feel like NetworkManager causes some problems but Im not sure. The most annoying thing is that I cant even update/upgrade anything due to lack of internet.

Comment: Try entering this into the terminal - `sudo systemctl mask systemd-suspend.service` and then reboot. If you need to undo this, it is - `sudo systemctl unmask systemd-suspend.service`.

Comment: @KGIII wow. To be honest I couldnt run it with sudo because terminal has frozen. Although I have run it without sudo, then I rebooted and it works now! Thanks! So I assume it was a problem with a permission right?

Comment: That's a whole new question, really. That's beyond the scope of this question that is dealing with the slow boot. I'm going to write up an answer that has a bit more information - I'll be including the 'sudo' bit, but you can try without it. (There's more you can disable.)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments and from your image:

Start with the process that is taking the longest. In this case, that process is `systemd-suspend.service`.

```
sudo systemctl mask systemd-suspend.service
```

If you need to re-enable it, then you just unmask it.

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-suspend.service
```

You can also try the following:

```
sudo systemctl disable ureadahead
sudo systemctl disable plymouth
sudo systemctl disable systemd.networkd.service
```

Those too may take some time off your boot and are relatively safe to disable.

Comment: Okay so I tried it. It even worked till the shut down. When I restarted the system the problem is back again to where it was. None of apps works, no internet connection, freezing after sudo command in terminal.

Comment: @Grzegorz-so - The freezing in sudo is an entirely different problem and will require a second question. If the network isn't working, just simply reverse it. `sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service` To undo any of them, it's 'enable' or 'unmask'. If you do them one at a time, you'll be able to tell which is holding you up. What I'd suggest you do is back away from this one first and then ask a new question about why sudo isn't working for you. That's a much more seriously problem. I'd deal with that first.

Comment: To be honest I think that all of these problems have one cause. Everything was working fine till yesterday. I tried to enable the internet with the command you told me but unfortunately still no connection. Is there any possibility to check the filesystem from the recovery mode? Or to update/upgrade the system from recovery mode? I tried almost everything and still nothing :/ I also uploaded the view from shutting down the system.

Comment: Oh, worst case is pretty easy. You just preserve /home/username and install anew. If you want to check the file system (which doesn't seem like it'd help) you can fsck from recovery mode or from a live USB/DVD. Not being able to use sudo shouldn't have anything to do with how long your boot takes. They're very much different things.

Comment: Ayyy. Okay. But another question which bothers me. When im in the grub menu, I go to recovery mode and then from recovery mode when I choose „resume normal boot” the system starts and works fine. How?

Comment: That'd be related to the question asked here. Check the systemd-analyze blame and look for differences. As for the sudo, you've probably hosed your profile and permissions. As I don't know what commands you've entered in the past, I can't really speculate as to how that happened. It often happens when newer users blindly follow online tutorials. It's not *really* their fault, but the fault of the authors.